# strings.Split acting weird

Tags: go

I am doing a simple strings.Split on a date.

The format is `2015-10-04`

```
month := strings.Split(date, "-")
```

output is `[2015 10 03]`.

If I do `month[0]` it returns 2015 but when I do month[1], it returns

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

Though it clearly isn't. Am I using it wrong? Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Something is off with your string, when I literally run that string and split it I get `[2015 10 04]`;

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a complete working example:

```
package main

import "strings"

func main() {
    date := "2015-01-02"
    month := strings.Split(date, "-")
    println(month[0])
    println(month[1])
    println(month[2])
}
```

Output:

```
2015
01
02
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/0KsywfAy8G)

---

Perhaps you're not using the correct "dash" character?  [There are lots](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/dashes.html):

```
+-------+--------+----------+
| glyph |       codes       |
+-------+--------+----------+
| -     | U+002D | &#45;    |
| ֊     | U+058A | &#1418;  |
| ־     | U+05BE | &#1470;  |
| ᠆     | U+1806 | &#6150;  |
| ‐     | U+2010 | &#8208;  |
| ‑     | U+2011 | &#8209;  |
| ‒     | U+2012 | &#8210;  |
| –     | U+2013 | &#8211;  |
| —     | U+2014 | &#8212;  |
| ―     | U+2015 | &#8213;  |
| ⁻     | U+207B | &#8315;  |
| ₋     | U+208B | &#8331;  |
| −     | U+2212 | &#8722;  |
| ﹘     | U+FE58 | &#65112; |
| ﹣     | U+FE63 | &#65123; |
| －     | U+FF0D | &#65293; |
+-------+--------+----------+
```

Here is the code with a different input string, which also throws an index out of bounds exception:

package main

```
import "strings"

func main() {
    date := "2015‐01‐02" // U+2010 dashes
    month := strings.Split(date, "-")
    println(month[0])
    println(month[1])
    println(month[2])
}
```

[Playground.](http://play.golang.org/p/YuY1OyjydR)

Comment: Yes I get that too. It has to indicate that the "string" Mitchell has is tainted in some way with invalid bytes or hidden characters.

Comment: @Allendar I agree.  I added in an example with other Unicode dashes which could be his problem

Comment: Yep, the dash did not match. Never would have figured that out, thanks!